# Outlook email with "Dropbox" header

Tags: email, spam-prevention

it's my first time here. My official email (I'm a PhD student) got spammed by "Dropbox."

[image]

I cannot receive emails and when I send ones they are sent under the shown header. I even deleted my dropbox account with this email. Still the problem persists. I'm using outlook to check my emails. Any help in getting rid of this is much appreciated.

Comment: does it persist on different browsers?

Comment: It does. In school I'm using explorer at home Chrome.